# Bootgrid using HTML in cell

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootgrid in my Asp.net MVC5 project to display some data:

```
<table id="grid-basic" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-column-id="id">ID</th>
        <th data-column-id="name">Name</th>
        <th data-column-id="actions">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (Test item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id</td>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span><b>Some Text</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that bootgrid removes my HTML code and not showing any icons I want to use. Does anybody know how I can use html in my cell, I couldn't find the answer in the bootgrid documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found a solution that works for me:
I can use data formaters:

```
$("#grid-basic").bootgrid({

    caseSensitive: false,
    columnSelection: false,

    formatters: {
        "commands": function (column, row) {
            return '<span class="icon glyphicon input-group-addon glyphicon-search"></span>';
        }
    }

});

<th data-column-id="actions" data-formatter="commands">Actions</th>
```